# How to remove stuck 50mm lens from my Canon dSLR?

Tags: lens, canon, repair

I have the Canon 600D and the "nifty fifty" 50mm f/1.8 that cost around 100$.
One day when I was trying to switch lenses, I pressed on the lens release button, started twisting the 50mm, and around 1/4 of the way the lens got stuck. Now I can't pull out the lens and I'm afraid to twist it harder. I did some research and I can't find any way to fix it, so I went to the local photography shop and the offer that they gave me was $130, which is more than the cost of the lens itself!

Does anyone know how I can get this lens off without breaking it?

Comment: Without breaking the lens? Probably not. But without breaking the camera, possibly. http://www.theroastedroot.net/removing-a-stuck-canon-50mm-f1-8-camera-lens/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help. It's not exactly what you wanted to hear but it's probably better than what the camera shop has advised.

[**How to remove a stuck Canon 50mm 1.8 lens from your camera**](http://500px.com/David_Epperly/stories/22176/how-to-remove-a-stuck-canon-50mm-1-8-lens-from-your-camera)

Note that this **may not** be what has happened in your case, but it sounds very similar.
He says -

- What happens is that there is a snap on plastic dust cover on the mount end of the lens. The dust cover is basically a plastic ring with four fingers that snap into the back of the lens housing. The cover encompasses the inner lens and also surrounds the electrical connections on three sides. Hopefully you are starting to get a picture of the part I am talking about. What happens is that one or more of the fingers that snaps into the back of the lens breaks allowing the dust cover to fall slightly back towards the camera body. When you go to rotate the lens to remove it the lens only rotates maybe one quarter of a turn and will not rotate any more. The plastic dust cover has snagged on the cameras electrical connection.

His fix is potentially destructive of the lens and not of the camera if care is taken. There is a possibility of saving the lens - and more so if you understand properly in advance what you are setting out to do, what is involved, why it works and what damage is likely. So read the (short) article carefully first. If you are not confident with your mechanical competence you could consider showing this 'fix' to a person who is used to fine mechanical work and ask them to try. I'd expect that a competent "watchmaker" would be likely to do this successfully.

---

It is also possible that, if this is what is wrong in your case, you may be able to plan an "attack" from the outside with pieces of material that allow you to attack the jamming points - perhaps mylar sheet or steel or brass shim material that you can cut "fingers from to slide into the lens-body interface. A mechanical "feeler gauge" set may provide suitable material. If trying this method, take the camera battery out first. Bearing in mind, of course, that damage to the lens is potentially acceptable but that damage to the camera is to be avoided.

If I was attempting this I'd read as many of the descriptions of the frontal attack method that I could find and look at the photos (see 'useful page' below) and THEN see if a feeler gauge attack may be able to be planned. That's just me, and you may be better advised to not even try this. If it does work it probably has more chance of actually recovering the lens than the other approaches. But, who knows what you might do to the camera in the process?

---

As a warning about brute force, he also notes:

- Some people said to just twist hard and the lens should break and come off. Others said that they twisted hard and the lens came off but it wiped out the camera side of the mount, meaning the electrical connection pins. The local camera repair shop had no idea what I was talking about so I decided to give it a go on my own.

---

**Related:**

The link from Inkista contains a link to [**this useful page**](https://www.flickr.com/groups/canonef50mm/discuss/72157617659556364/) of people's accounts of experiences with this lens. There are similar suggestions to those from the site above. All seem to suggest that you need to 'go in' from the lens front and I did not note any suggesting my 'feeler gauge' approach.

[How **NOT** to do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcrhYnXqEuM)

Comment: Thank you very much for the amazing answer. I will try to save my lens. do you think that if the dust cover will break I will be able to replace it with another one(this time metal one) from ebay?
like this: [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/360994358304?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2648&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT)

Comment: @HackinGuiy I don't know if the later model II cover fits your lens But, note that that company is offering parts installation service and may offer complete repair at an acceptable price. Whether that's a good choice is up to you.

Comment: If the lens is prone to getting stuck like this, I'd not care about saving it, I'd be more interested in disposing myself of it and upgrading to something better made.

Comment: @user1515834 It's a shame that Canon reduced quality below an acceptable level in this manner. BUT note that [**the replacement plate that HackinGuiy identified**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/360994358304?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2648&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) for $US9.99  is made of metal (probably due to the failures) and is likely not to fail in the same way. It looks like it MAY be worthwhile for owners of these lenses to change or modify the bases plate prior to failures occurring. ....

Comment: @user1515834 .... DxO lens evaluations suggest that the MkII (Mk1 apparently not tested) is an acceptable but not stunning performer and if I owned one then say $15 plus an hour or few of fun would probably be worth expending in this manner. Each to their own.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Lens felt down, I wanted to test it and put it on the body. It worked but then the lens got stuck.

I managed to repair it with help of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15tUQhVMScc

- The plastic ring that is removed in the video at 1:03 was loose inside my cam
- I followed the steps of the video starting at 1:40
- up to 3:20 because the cable was still fixed at the back of the lens
- I used my finger to pull the loose plastic ring towards me until it snapped back in
- after that the lens can be removed an put back together

Lens and camera are working fine...

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! I was freaking out.

Comment: This worked for me as well after my 1yo daughter pulled the camera down to the ground. (disassemble front with help from youtube and use finger to snap ring back in from the inside). Camera works, don't know about the lens yet as a plastic ring broke internally and my epoxy repair is still setting. If it doesn't however, it's from the fall, not the fix! Thanks again Joe.